# import javax.comm*; error

Tags: java, serial-port, classpath

do i need to install netbeans 6.8 for serial port support?

`import javax.comm*;` gives an error in my netbeans 5.5.1 ... what could be the actual problem?

i downloaded comm api jar folder from : http://www.oreilly.com.tw/bookcode/java_io/ where to add this one so that import javax.comm.* won't give any error

Comment: You're missing a dot: it should be import javax.comm.*

Answer (score 1):

[Download the COMM API from here](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_SMI-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=JAVACOMM-3.0.1-LX-SP-G-F@CDS-CDS_SMI) and add the jar to your netbeans classpath.

Even if that works for you, I still suggest upgrading to NetBeans 6.8. Version 5.5 is too outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a better link which consist of a zip containing the jat file i.e. :--

http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip

Answer (score 0):

No path or Netbeans upgrade nessicary I believe, just add the files from the comm library to the right folders. For me these directories are relative to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre`, but they need to go in your Java JRE folder:

1. The .jar in /lib/ext
2. The .properties in /lib
3. The .dll in /bin

Answer (score 0):

if you use eclipse, i suggest you can select your project and Click the right mouse button at first.then select   son menu named "Add Extern JARs"of menu named"buildpath", find your comm.jar you have download al last. i have slove this problem follow this steps.